# REST API url filtering design

Tags: rest, uri

I've been looking around and most folks seem to recommend designing filtering with ranges in REST API URLs using the bracket notation (e.g. **/resource?weight[gte]=1&weight[lte]=5**) or some variation of this...

But is there any reason we can't just use a delimiter and document the expected order in API docs? e.g. **/resource?weight=1_5**...where the API docs would inform the client that pattern is min_max

Are there any pros or cons to both the above that would warrant one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any pros or cons to both the above that would warrant one over the other?

Yes.

First: the URI production rules in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A) do not permit LEFT SQUARE BRACKET and RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET in the query part of the URI - those characters have to be pct-encoded.

Second: we don't have a good way to communicate bespoke query value delimiters to general purpose components.  What you are proposing to do here is analogous to having a single input control for two values - and telling the human being using the form that they should type text using a specific schema.  But we really don't have a standardized language for that.

There's already a lot of work done in standardizing [URI Templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570), your default options should be limited to the mechanisms described there.  In a code review, I'd push back against your proposal if you didn't have compelling supporting evidence ready.

Comment: gotcha, I also found this colon approach - /items?price=gte:10&price=lte:100 - is that still better than the delimiter approach? this is for an internal api if that makes any difference